# get the difference between a date/time and a integer value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, difference

I have two variables (i.e. two columns in SQL table) , one is a datetime format, e.g. 2011-12-31 00:00:00, and the other is integer format, e.g 201203, I want to get the difference in months between these two variables, what is the most efficient way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: you need to tell us about a lot requirements here.  One of your dates has a day in it -- another does not.   Do you want to treat your date as not having a day or your string as always being on the same day?

Comment: The string has different days. I do not care which day it is. I just need the difference month. Thanks.

Comment: You should stop storing dates in string columns. If you store datetime values in datetime datatypes this becomes so much simpler. To get the difference you will first have to cast these to a datetime and then it becomes simple using DATEADD.

Comment: `what is the most efficient way to do it?` save your date\time using a datetime field.

Comment: I was given the data....I did not create it.....

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need to convert the string or integer field into a datetime field, then use the date functions.

Assuming it is a string field:

```
create function dbo.DatePictureToDateTime(@datePicture varchar(20))
returns datetime
as
begin
    return 
    case 
    -- YYYYMM case
    when @datePicture like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9]' 
    then convert(datetime, left(@datePicture, 4) + '-' + substring(@datePicture, 5, 2) + '-01', 121)
    -- YYYYMMDD case
    when @datePicture like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]' 
    then convert(datetime, left(@datePicture, 4) + '-' + substring(@datePicture, 5, 2) + '-' + substring(@datepicture, 7, 2), 121)
    -- Add your own cases for different date strings you have
    end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
select dbo.DatePictureToDateTime(datePicture), datePicture
from (
select '201103' as datepicture
union all select '20110330' as datepicture
)x
```

If the date field is an integer:

```
dbo.DatePictureToDateTime(cast(dateInteger as varchar(20))
```

To convert the months difference, use `datediff`:

```
-- Datediff returns the number of period ends between the two datetimes
-- in this case it returns the number of month ends, 
--   i.e. how many midnights on the last day of a month
datediff(month, dateField, dbo.DatePictureToDateTime(datePictureField))
```

Note the definition of datediff:

- from 31 January to 1 February is 1 day difference, and also 1 month difference.
- From 1 February to 28 February is 27 days difference, but **zero** months.

If that's not what you want you have to ask another question. Date calculations are complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the String date to a Date with (you might need to set the conversion format)

```
CONVERT(DATE, @DateAsString)
```

Convert the YearMonth Int to YearMonthDay (on the first of the month) then to a Date with

```
CONVERT(DATE, CAST((@DateAsInt*100 + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)), 101)
```

So, in one line:

```
DECLARE @DateAsInt INT = 201203
DECLARE @DateAsString VARCHAR(19) = '2011-12-31 00:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, @DateAsString), CONVERT(DATE, CAST((@DateAsInt*100 + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)), 101))
```